# Return a list of attributes from a list of objects

Tags: python, sockets

I'm developing a simple TCP chat application server-client to learn Python and I'm not sure about data structures to use.

Server side I've defined `client` class and its attributes: socket, username, room and online_status. Every client is added to `clients` list and also, at the same time, its socket is added to `connections` list.  Server runs in an always-true loop listening for incoming messages using the following declaration

```
(ready_to_read, _, _) = select.select([server_socket] + list(connections), [], [])
```

Is there any way to list every `socket` of every `client` objects and do like

```
(ready_to_read, _, _) = select.select( list(client.socket), [], [])
```

Comment: I see no obvious flaw in what you propose but it does lack context; have you tried your proposed code? As documented [select.select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) does what you are hoping. Guessing from what little is in your question, might you want to generate a list of `clients.socket`? More code would certainly help your question be answerable.

Comment: That's right. I won't another list called `connections` when I have a clients class list, the first piece of code is working. My problem is `client.socket` syntax is not correct, always throws `client` has no attribute `socket`. So maybe correct question would be how to list all object instances attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure that I have really understood what you want, but assuming that you want to build a list of sockets from the list of client instances, you can use a list comprehension:

```
(ready_to_read, _, _) = select.select( [client.socket for client in clients], [], [])
```

(assuming `clients` is a list of the client instances)